# redux find and replace state object

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have got a board with multiple card items on it, i want to implement a edit functionality where if clicked the user can then type a new `title` and `description` for the card. I Can do all of it successfully until i get to the reducer where i am trying to update the store to reflect user `edit` action.

the edit payload object is:

```
{
    "title": "dasdsads 123456",
    "description": "asdsadsad 1234565",
    "id": "badb4cbb-a66c-5c5d-57ee-5401eeaac0cd"
}
```

my state:

```
   {
  ideaBoard: {
    tiles: [
      {
        title: 'dasdsads',
        description: 'asdsadsad',
        id: '0e62aa65-d465-6b73-3747-7e2f654d96d6',
        createdAt: '28/10/2022, 00:31:32'
      },
      {
        title: 'dasdsads 123',
        description: 'asdsadsad 123',
        id: 'badb4cbb-a66c-5c5d-57ee-5401eeaac0cd',
        createdAt: '28/10/2022, 00:31:39'
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

My reducer `updateTile`

```
updateTile: (state, { payload }): any => {
  const update: any = state.tiles.find((tile) => tile["id"] === payload.id);


  return {

  };
},
```

So i was thinking to first find a matching id between the payload id with one of the state id. Once i find it i want to replace that object from the state with the payload object

Answer (score 0):

Just `Array#map` over the `titles` field in the state and replace the particular `title` object.

```
updateTile: (state, { payload }): any => {
  return {
    ...state,
    titles: state.titles.map((title) => title.id === payload.id ? 
      { ...title, ...payload } : title),
  };
},
```

Comment: Hi @Kind user thank you for your suggestion, but why would i map over titles? should i be maping over tiles array? and would like to replace all values in the found objects

Comment: @John State has to be immutable and mapping is the way to go.

Comment: Yep I agree with immutability, probably should have mentioned but i am using redux toolkit, and you can directly mutate the state as redux toolkit uses immer behind the scene